# babel-plugin-module-resolver intellisense with vs code

Tags: javascript, react-native, babel-plugin-module-resolver

babel-plugin-module-resolver is working fine but IntelliSense is not working in vs code, please check my integrations and let me know what's going wrong here. with all these code integrations my imports are resolved but without IntelliSense, I have to write down the complete name of the component or copy it from the export file and paste it where I need to use it.

**Visual Studio Code Version: 1.77.3 (Universal)**

library information

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.6",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
```

here is **.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      'babel-module': {
        extensions: ['.js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'jsx', '.ios.js', '.android.js', '.json'],
        alias: {
          actions: './actions',
          api: './api',
          assets: './assets',
          components: './components',
          navigation: './navigation',
          reducers: './reducers',
          sagas: './sagas',
          screens: './screens',
          store: './store',
          utils: './utils'
        },
      },
    },
  },

};
```

here is **babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    ['module-resolver',
      {
        extensions: ['.js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'jsx', '.ios.js', '.android.js', '.json'],
        alias: {
          actions: './actions',
          api: './api',
          assets: './assets',
          components: './components',
          navigation: './navigation',
          reducers: './reducers',
          sagas: './sagas',
          screens: './screens',
          store: './store',
          utils: './utils'
        },
      }
    ],
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin', {
        relativeSourceLocation: true,
      },
    ]
  ],
};
```

here is **jsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": {
      "actions/*": [
        "./actions/*"
      ],
      "api/*": [
        "./api/*"
      ],
      "assets/*": [
        "./assets/*"
      ],
      "components/*": [
        "./components/*"
      ],
      "navigation/*": [
        "./navigation/*"
      ],
      "reducers/*": [
        "./reducers/*"
      ],
      "sagas/*": [
        "./sagas/*"
      ],
      "screens/*": [
        "./screens/*"
      ],
      "store/*": [
        "./store/*"
      ],
      "utils/*": [
        "./utils/*"
      ]
    },
  },
}
```